# ZMQ vs FTP for file transfer

Tags: ftp, zeromq

**Here is the challenge** :

> many (sender) servers must send files to many (receiver) servers. And
>   when a file is received on a server, then the receiver must trigger an
>   action. And I must add : the file transfer is really a big deal.

One solution has been suggested :

> developing a program in C, which uses ZMQ for everything

Personally, I am not sure that this is a good solution.

Why should it be necessary to develop a custom file transfer protocol on top of ZMQ, knowing that FTP exists and client/server FTP libraries are available in many programming languages ? It seems to me that it is like reinventing the wheel.

One argument has been advanced : FTP is "heavy". Well, I don't see why FTP is particularly "heavy", and I am not that we can do better (or, at least, significantly better - to justify the cost) with an implementation of a custom file transfer protocol on top of ZMQ.

Secondly, I am not sure that using C is a good idea either knowing that the file transfer software is [IO bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound) : the performances essentially depend on the network bandwidth and, to a lesser extent on the disks performances. Using assembly language to write a file transfer program won't do better than using C, which won't do better than using Python or GO (for example) : the program essentially waits for the IOs to terminate. Using C only makes the code longer (in terms of length and complexity), knowing that we have to take care of all the low-level details (thread-safe programming with sockets, timeout management...).

I would advocate another approach :

- using a high-level programming language that takes care of many low-level details (ex : Python, GO).
- using FTP for the file transfers, through a client/server FTP library. Reinventing the wheel is not a good idea.
- using ZMQ for exchanging messages. When an FTP receiver receives a file, it triggers an action through the sending of a message through a ZMQ channel. And, for that, *using C is like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut*.

Do you see any good reason to use ZMQ+C for everything ?

Comment: I get the sense that most of your anxiety stems from the mere thought of using C. Correct me if I'm wrong. If the problem is the language, why not go with a [language](http://wiki.zeromq.org/bindings:_start) you like? If the problem is whether or not zeromq is cut out for the job of file transfer, well I'd invite you to first read the zeromq [file transfer guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/hx:chapter7#Transferring-Files), then carry out your benchmarks, and make your decision from there.

Comment: Well... I am not afraid of using C. The client wants to use C. However, my fear comes from the fact that the client does not know precisely what he wants, and the solution must interact with many specific services (for which API exists in many languages, except C - probably because there is no point for making REST calls using C). From my point of view, considering this situation, I should use a high-level programming language, rather than a low level one.